# SassError: The render() method is only available in Node.js

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, jenkins, npm

I am having a react application, which is using TypeScript. When I am trying to build it using a Jenkins server, I am running into the below error:

```
+ npm run buildprod
npm info using npm@9.5.0 ---------------> 1
npm info using node@v18.14.2

> app-name@0.1.0 buildprod
> CI=false npm run build && mkdir dist && tar -zcvf dist/app-ui-1.0.0.tar.gz build/*

npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@6.14.15 -------------> 2
npm info using node@v18.14.2
npm info lifecycle app-name@0.1.0~prebuild: app-name@0.1.0
npm info lifecycle app-name@0.1.0~build: app-name@0.1.0

> app-name@0.1.0 build /usr/mware/jenkins-ws/workspace/app/app_dev/APP_UI_DEV/app-ui-pipeline
> env-cmd -f ./env/.env.production react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

SassError: SassError: The render() method is only available in Node.js.


npm info lifecycle app-name@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! app-name@0.1.0 build: `env-cmd -f ./env/.env.production react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

I am not sure, why npm is throwing this error, where as just before this stage, I am installing the packages too, that is happening successfully, every time. But, `npm build` is getting failed with the above error. The same pipeline used to run completely and successfully, before.

I am also noticing that it is using different versions of npm, you can compare line number 1 and 2.

Any reason, why this is happening?